# Erratic behavior in script where both scale and positioning are dynamic - why?

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinate-transformation

I've been tring to isolate a bug that creates erratic behavior when both the scale and position of the square in the script below are dynamic. The goal of the script below is to make a square fade up and down in different positions and scales around the screen. If either or both scaling and positioning is fixed, then the behavior is as expected - the square fades up and down at regular intervals and in different positions or at different scales (or both fixed position and scale). If both scaling and position are dynamic, however, then the square occasionally doesn't appear on screen at all and eventually barely if ever. What's going on?

I've put sections for dynamic and fixed scaling/positioning in the snippet below so you can try for yourself and see what's happening. Currently, I have both set to dynamic so you can see the intermittent behavior I'm describing. Thanks for taking a look and giving me your thoughts!

**UPDATE:** Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/qwns3x9L/) as well if you prefer working that way.

```js
var container, renderer, scene, camera;
var gridComposer, finalComposer;
var container = document.body;

var frustrumWidth, frustrumHeight;
var frustrumSize = 1000;
var aspect; // = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var zoom = 0.5;
var imageWidth, imageHeight;

var width, height;

// Light Spot
var spot;



function init() {

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

    aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( frustrumSize * aspect / - 2, frustrumSize * aspect / 2, frustrumSize / 2, frustrumSize / - 2, 0, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
    camera.zoom = zoom;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    frustrumWidth = (frustrumSize * aspect);
    frustrumHeight = frustrumSize;

    imageWidth = (frustrumWidth * 2);
    imageHeight = (frustrumHeight * 2);


    ///////////////////////////
    // Create the LIGHT spot //
    ///////////////////////////

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var opacity = 0.7;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ transparent: true, opacity: opacity, color: 0xffff00 });
    var spotSize;
    spotSize = 200;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(spotSize, spotSize);
    geometry.dynamic = true;
    var z = 1.01;
    var startPosition = chooseAWindowPosition( spotSize );
    startPosition.z = z;
    geometry.translate( startPosition.x, startPosition.y, startPosition.z );
    var fading = true;
    spot = [ new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material), fading, opacity, startPosition, spotSize ];
    scene.add(spot[0]);
    

    ////////////////////////
    // Create AxesHelpers //
    ////////////////////////

    // top left
    var axes1 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes1.geometry.translate( -(imageWidth/2)+10, (imageHeight/2)-10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes1 );

    // top right
    var axes2 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes2.geometry.translate( (imageWidth/2)-10, (imageHeight/2)-10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes2 );

    // bottom left
    var axes3 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes3.geometry.translate( -(imageWidth/2)+10, -(imageHeight/2)+10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes3 );

    // bottom right
    var axes4 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes4.geometry.translate( (imageWidth/2)-10, -(imageHeight/2)+10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes4 );

    // middle
    var axes5 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    scene.add( axes5 );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    render();
    
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) { // min and max included
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function generateTranslationValues( beginPosition, endPosition ) { // generates the translate() values needed to move from one position to another
    var xDifference = endPosition.x - beginPosition.x;
    var yDifference = endPosition.y - beginPosition.y;
    var translateValues = new THREE.Vector3( xDifference, yDifference, 0 );
    console.log("beginPosition:");
    console.log(beginPosition);
    console.log("endPosition:");
    console.log(endPosition);
    console.log("translation values:");
    console.log(translateValues);
    return translateValues;
}

function generateScaleValue( origSpotSize, newSpotSize ) { // generates the scale values needed to rescale from one spot size to another
    scaleValue = newSpotSize / origSpotSize;
    console.log("Start size: " + origSpotSize);
    console.log("End size: " + newSpotSize);
    console.log("Scale value: " + scaleValue);
    return scaleValue;
}

function chooseAWindowPosition( spotSize ) {
    var position;
    var x;
    var y;
    x = randomIntFromInterval( -imageWidth / 2, imageWidth / 2 );
    y = randomIntFromInterval( -imageHeight / 2, imageHeight / 2 );
    position = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, 0 );
    console.log( "-imageWidth / 2 is" +  (-imageWidth / 2) );
    console.log( "imageWidth / 2 is" +  (imageWidth / 2) );
    console.log( "-imageHeight / 2 is" +  (-imageHeight / 2) );
    console.log( "imageHeight / 2 is" +  (imageHeight / 2) );
    console.log( "spotSize is: " + spotSize );
    console.log("position is:");
    console.log(position);
    return position;
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    updateLightSpot();
}

function updateLightSpot() {
    var fading = spot[1];
    if ( fading ) {
        spot[0].material.opacity-=0.007;
    } else { // if not fading
        spot[0].material.opacity+=0.007;
    }
    var opacityLimit = spot[2];
    var newFadeValue;
    if ( spot[0].material.opacity >= opacityLimit ) {
        spot[0].material.opacity = opacityLimit;
        newFadeValue = true;
        spot[1] = newFadeValue;
    } else if ( spot[0].material.opacity <= 0 ) {
        // >>> SCALING SECTION <<<
        var newSpotSize;
            // >>> FIXED SCALE <<<
        // newSpotSize = 200;
        // spot[4] = newSpotSize;
            // >>> DYNAMIC SCALE <<<
        newSpotSize = randomIntFromInterval( imageHeight*0.1, imageHeight*0.5 );
        var scaleValue;
        scaleValue = generateScaleValue( spot[4], newSpotSize );
        spot[0].geometry.scale( scaleValue, scaleValue, 1 ); // no change in scale for z
        spot[4] = newSpotSize;

        // >>> POSITIONING SECTION <<<
        var newPosition;
            // >>> FIXED POSITION <<<
        // newPosition = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        // var translateValues;
        // translateValues = generateTranslationValues( spot[3], newPosition );
        // spot[0].geometry.translate( translateValues.x, translateValues.y, translateValues.z );
        // spot[3] = newPosition;
            // >>> DYNAMIC POSITION <<<
        newPosition = chooseAWindowPosition( newSpotSize );
        var translateValues;
        translateValues = generateTranslationValues( spot[3], newPosition );
        spot[0].geometry.translate( translateValues.x, translateValues.y, translateValues.z );
        spot[3] = newPosition;

        newFadeValue = false;
        spot[1] = newFadeValue;
    }
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>three.js webgl - row of stripes with orthographic camera</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   body {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family:Monospace;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   #info {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index:100;
   }
   a { color: #ff0000 }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="info">Row Test</div>
  <!-- <div id="container"></div> -->

  <script src="three_95.js"></script>
  <script src="CopyShader.js"></script>
  <script src="EffectComposer.js"></script>
  <script src="RenderPass.js"></script>
  <script src="ShaderPass.js"></script>
  <script src="SubtractiveShader.js"></script>


  <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="stripesvertexshader">
        
         
         void main() {
             vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
             gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
         }

     </script>

     <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="stripesfragmentshader">
         
         void main() {
             gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5 );
             gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor
         }

     </script>

  <!-- Custom Scripts -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate the relative translation of the object, then you subtract the current position of the object (`spot[3]`) form the new position (`newPosition`).

When you scale the object, then not only the size of the object is scaled, but its position (translation) of the object is scaled, too.
This causes that your calculation of the relative translation is wrong, because it is base on the "unscaled" position of the object.

To solve your issue, you have to scale the stored position (`spot[3]`), too:

```
newSpotSize = randomIntFromInterval( imageHeight*0.1, imageHeight*0.5 );
var scaleValue = generateScaleValue( spot[4], newSpotSize );
spot[0].geometry.scale( scaleValue, scaleValue, 1 ); // no change in scale for z
spot[4] = newSpotSize;
spot[3].x *= scaleValue;
spot[3].y *= scaleValue;
```

See the example, where I applied the suggested changes to you original code:

```js
var container, renderer, scene, camera;
var gridComposer, finalComposer;
var container = document.body;

var frustrumWidth, frustrumHeight;
var frustrumSize = 1000;
var aspect; // = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var zoom = 0.5;
var imageWidth, imageHeight;

var width, height;

// Light Spot
var spot;



function init() {

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

    aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( frustrumSize * aspect / - 2, frustrumSize * aspect / 2, frustrumSize / 2, frustrumSize / - 2, 0, 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );
    camera.zoom = zoom;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    frustrumWidth = (frustrumSize * aspect);
    frustrumHeight = frustrumSize;

    imageWidth = (frustrumWidth * 2);
    imageHeight = (frustrumHeight * 2);


    ///////////////////////////
    // Create the LIGHT spot //
    ///////////////////////////

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var opacity = 0.7;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ transparent: true, opacity: opacity, color: 0xffff00 });
    var spotSize;
    spotSize = 200;
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(spotSize, spotSize);
    geometry.dynamic = true;
    var z = 1.01;
    var startPosition = chooseAWindowPosition( spotSize );
    startPosition.z = z;
    geometry.translate( startPosition.x, startPosition.y, startPosition.z );
    var fading = true;
    spot = [ new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material), fading, opacity, startPosition, spotSize ];
    scene.add(spot[0]);
    

    ////////////////////////
    // Create AxesHelpers //
    ////////////////////////

    // top left
    var axes1 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes1.geometry.translate( -(imageWidth/2)+10, (imageHeight/2)-10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes1 );

    // top right
    var axes2 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes2.geometry.translate( (imageWidth/2)-10, (imageHeight/2)-10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes2 );

    // bottom left
    var axes3 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes3.geometry.translate( -(imageWidth/2)+10, -(imageHeight/2)+10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes3 );

    // bottom right
    var axes4 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    axes4.geometry.translate( (imageWidth/2)-10, -(imageHeight/2)+10, 0.01 );
    scene.add( axes4 );

    // middle
    var axes5 = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    scene.add( axes5 );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    render();
    
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) { // min and max included
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function generateTranslationValues( beginPosition, endPosition ) { // generates the translate() values needed to move from one position to another
    var xDifference = endPosition.x - beginPosition.x;
    var yDifference = endPosition.y - beginPosition.y;
    var translateValues = new THREE.Vector3( xDifference, yDifference, 0 );
    console.log("beginPosition:");
    console.log(beginPosition);
    console.log("endPosition:");
    console.log(endPosition);
    console.log("translation values:");
    console.log(translateValues);
    return translateValues;
}

function generateScaleValue( origSpotSize, newSpotSize ) { // generates the scale values needed to rescale from one spot size to another
    scaleValue = newSpotSize / origSpotSize;
    console.log("Start size: " + origSpotSize);
    console.log("End size: " + newSpotSize);
    console.log("Scale value: " + scaleValue);
    return scaleValue;
}

function chooseAWindowPosition( spotSize ) {
    var position;
    var x;
    var y;
    x = randomIntFromInterval( -imageWidth / 2, imageWidth / 2 );
    y = randomIntFromInterval( -imageHeight / 2, imageHeight / 2 );
    position = new THREE.Vector3( x, y, 0 );
    console.log( "-imageWidth / 2 is" +  (-imageWidth / 2) );
    console.log( "imageWidth / 2 is" +  (imageWidth / 2) );
    console.log( "-imageHeight / 2 is" +  (-imageHeight / 2) );
    console.log( "imageHeight / 2 is" +  (imageHeight / 2) );
    console.log( "spotSize is: " + spotSize );
    console.log("position is:");
    console.log(position);
    return position;
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    updateLightSpot();
}

function updateLightSpot() {
    var fading = spot[1];
    if ( fading ) {
        spot[0].material.opacity-=0.007;
    } else { // if not fading
        spot[0].material.opacity+=0.007;
    }
    var opacityLimit = spot[2];
    var newFadeValue;
    if ( spot[0].material.opacity >= opacityLimit ) {
        spot[0].material.opacity = opacityLimit;
        newFadeValue = true;
        spot[1] = newFadeValue;
    } else if ( spot[0].material.opacity <= 0 ) {
        // >>> SCALING SECTION <<<
          var newSpotSize;
            // >>> FIXED SCALE <<<
        //newSpotSize = 200;
        //spot[4] = newSpotSize;
            // >>> DYNAMIC SCALE <<<
        newSpotSize = randomIntFromInterval( imageHeight*0.1, imageHeight*0.5 );
        var scaleValue = generateScaleValue( spot[4], newSpotSize );
        spot[0].geometry.scale( scaleValue, scaleValue, 1 ); // no change in scale for z
        spot[4] = newSpotSize;
        spot[3].x *= scaleValue;
        spot[3].y *= scaleValue;

        // >>> POSITIONING SECTION <<<
        var newPosition;
            // >>> FIXED POSITION <<<
        newPosition = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        //var translateValues;
        //translateValues = generateTranslationValues( spot[3], newPosition );
        //spot[0].geometry.translate( translateValues.x, translateValues.y, translateValues.z );
        //spot[3] = newPosition;
            // >>> DYNAMIC POSITION <<<
        newPosition = chooseAWindowPosition( newSpotSize );
        var translateValues;
        translateValues = generateTranslationValues( spot[3], newPosition );
        spot[0].geometry.translate( translateValues.x, translateValues.y, translateValues.z );
        spot[3] = newPosition;
        newFadeValue = false;
        spot[1] = newFadeValue;
    }
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="stripesvertexshader">
void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="stripesfragmentshader">   
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5 );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ah! This is great. Thanks!